# Can't load data from the server using ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I am pretty new to all of these technologies (php, knockout, and ajax).

> I am trying to load data from phpMyAdmin DB but it seems like my ajax
>   call is not executed. The loadData function in my js is called in HTML
>   and it controls the visibility of the table in my UI. Meaning, the
>   table will be visible only when there I get data from the server.

**my html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-2.2.0.js'></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container" data-bind="load: loadData()">

  <table data-bind="visible: people().length > 0" class="students">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Remove</th>
              <th>Update</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
          <tr>
              <td>
                  <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <span data-bind="text: age"></span>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>  
</div>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='studentapp.js'></script>
</html>
```

**js**

```
var personModel = function(id, name, age){
  var self = this; //caching so that it can be accessed later in a different context
  self.id = ko.observable(id); //unique id for the student (auto increment primary key from the database)
  self.name = ko.observable(name); //name of the student
  self.age = ko.observable(age);
};

var model = function () {
var self = this;
self.people = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.loadData = function () {
    //console.log("AHAHAHAH");
     // alert("super");
     //fetch existing student data from database$(document).ready(function() {
     $.getJSON("refresher_save.php", function(data) {
        for(var x in data){
          //student details
          var id = data[x]['id'];
          var name = data[x]['name'];
          var age = data[x]['age'];

          //push each of the student record to the observable array for 
          //storing student data
          self.people.push(new personModel(id, name, age)); 
        }
     });
};
```

};

```
ko.applyBindings(new model());
```

**php**

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'student');

$action = (!empty($_POST['action'])) ? $_POST['action'] : ''; //action to be used(insert, delete, update, fetch)
$student = (!empty($_POST['student'])) ? $_POST['student'] : ''; //an array of the student details

//check if the student is not an empty string
//and assigns a value to $name and $age if its not empty
if(!empty($student)){
  $name = $student['name'];
  $age = $student['age'];    
}

switch($action){
    default:
              //only select student records which aren't deleted
              $students = $db->query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE status = 1");
              $students_r = array();

              while($row = $students->fetch_array()){

                  //default student data
                  $id = $row['id'];
                  $name = $row['name'];
                  $age = $row['age'];

                  //update status
                  //its false by default since
                  //this is only true if the user clicks
                  //on the span
                  $name_update = false;
                  $age_update = false;

                  //build the array that will store all the student records
                  $students_r[] = array(
                      'id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'age' => $age
                      );
              }

              echo json_encode($students_r); //convert the array to JSON string
            break;
}
?>
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: may be you need to `JSON.parse(data)` first, then loop through the `json` data

Comment: @AmitSoni No OP is using `dataType: 'json',`

Comment: Note that you're doing a GET request, but expecting POST data ?

Comment: ↑↑↑ and `$.ajax({
              alert("inside ajax");` is syntax error

Comment: ajax call structure is wayward check this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ . side note in `personModel` you decalred `var self=this` but still using `this` i.e `this.id` make it `self.id` . cheers

Comment: @adeneo , can you tell me where in the code am I doing that please?

Comment: @A.Wolff,so is there any other way of checking whether the ajax call was made or not?

Comment: @bangbang Use relevant callbacks `success` and `error` or check your network tab in browser console. But you should firstly learn how to debug javascript. BTW, don't forget adeneo's comment ↯↯↯

Comment: `$.ajax` sends a GET request by default, you have to specifically specify POST.

Comment: @adeneo, from my understnding , the ajax call gets the data from the server via PHP and populates the data in the peoples array. So, I need the ajax to so a GET and not  a POST, right?

Comment: Does `refresher_save.php`  echos json string when you brows the file?

Comment: @DatoJanez, the console is empty.

Comment: @adeneo `php` file is not using any parameter on this request, it doesn't need `$_POST['student']` or `$_POST['action']` variables, switch should go to default action and should echo `json`. 
@bangbang can you access file directly through browser?

Comment: @DatoJanez, no I can't. I tried to find it but I did not see it.

Comment: If I put html tags around my php fil and run it, it actually prints out the database values. But I am surprised that the ajax call cannot get the same data. Any ideas?

Comment: I have also changed my code to use getJSON instead of ajax but it's stil not retrieving the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line:

```
<div class="container" data-bind="load: loadData()">
```

should say this instead:

```
<div class="container" data-bind="load: $root.loadData()">
```

To prove this out, in the browser console run the following:

```
ko.contextFor(document.body).$root
```

You should see your view model return as an object you can browse in the console.

You also may want to move your import for studentapp.js to the top of the code beneath your KO and JQuery imports.

As @A.Wolff suggested, I would put your code inside the success callback.

And, this code will not work, you need to reference the element you are iterating in the loop.

```
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
      <tr>
          <td>
              <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
          </td>
          <td>
              <span data-bind="text: age"></span>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
```

It should be:

```
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
      <tr>
          <td>
              <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>
          </td>
          <td>
              <span data-bind="text: $data.age"></span>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
```